# Join tables query in SQL Server 2012 

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables like below:

```
TableA --> categoryId(pk), categoryParentId, catName
TableB --> empId(pk), categoryId, empName, empDesignation
```

[image]

I want to get all `catName` with respective categoryId from `TableA` where `categoryId=2` of `TableB` is equal to `categoryParentId=2` of `TableA`. Please help.

Result:

```
1002   SE
1003   MD
```

Comment: For clarity, can you provide what you would like your result set to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT catName FROM TABLEA WHERE categoryParentId IN (SELECT DISTINCT categoryID from TABLEB);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Little change I want in the query i.e. categoryId of tableB is 2 and select catName as well as respective categoryId.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `INNER JOIN`:

```
select TableA.catName
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.categoryParentId = TableB.categoryId
```

Using `INNER JOIN` is the recommended way to use for joining tables (as opposed to `SELECT ... FROM TableA, TableB ...`)

See:

- [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)
  *(this question was actually about MySql, but the answers say that it's the same for SQL Server)*
- [Difference in INNER join and cartesian join in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029947/difference-in-inner-join-and-cartesian-join-in-sql-server)

---

Answering your comment (I assume that you wanted the `categoryId` from `TableA`):

```
select TableA.catName, TableA.categoryId
from TableA
inner join TableB on TableA.categoryParentId = TableB.categoryId
where TableB.categoryId = 2
```

Comment: I want categoryId of tableB equal to 2 and select catName as well as respective categoryId.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will fulfill your need

```
    SELECT TABLEA.CATNAME AS CATEGORY
    from TABLEB INNER JOIN TABLEA 
    ON TABLEA.CATEGORYPARENTID = TABLEB.CATEGORYID
```

Answer (score 0):

another method...

```
SELECT 
  catname
from
  tablea a INNER JOIN
  tableb b ON 
    a.categoryParentID = b.categoryID
  group by
  catname
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT tableA.catName
 FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableB.categoryId = table1.categoryParentId
  AND tableB.categoryId = 2;
```

If you want the unique catNames, you can use

```
SELECT distinct tableA.catName
 FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableB.categoryId = table1.categoryParentId
  AND tableB.categoryId = 2;
```

Comment: For categoryId of tableB equal to 2 and select catName as well as respective categoryId.